# TypeError: Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference Angularjs Breeze

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I'm getting the following exception after fetching the data from the breeze controller.

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference

Here is my code:

**Student.js**

```
function fetchUsers()
{
    return repository.GetAllUsers().then(function querySucceeded(data) {
        // Looks like the problem with the above 'then'
        vm.allUsers = data;
        return vm.allUsers;
    });
}
```

**repository.js:**

```
function GetAllUsers()
{                
    var query = EntityQuery.from('users');
    manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded, _queryFailed);               

    function querySucceeded(data) {                                    
        log('Retrieved [Lookups]', data, true);    
        return data.results;  //Here I can see the fetched data from breeze controller.
    }
}
```

When I replace then with `to$q`, I see the following exception:

> Object doesn't support property or method `to$q`

Comment: `GetAllUsers()` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

The `GetAllUsers` function has no `return` statement at the top level.

If the intention is to return a **chained** promise that resolves to `data.results`, include a `return` statement at each level of the nested hierarchy.

```
function GetAllUsers() {                
    var query = EntityQuery.from('users');

    //return derived promise     
    return (
        manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded, _queryFailed)
    );               

    function querySucceeded(data) {                                    
        log('Retrieved [Lookups]', data, true);
        //return for chaining    
        return data.results;  //Here I can see the fetched data from breeze controller.
    };
};
```

Nested functions need `return` statements at each level. Without that, the function returns `null`, resulting in the *Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference* error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply. That helps.